# Arzela-Ascoli: Proof?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

**Problem**

Given a compact domain.

Regard the function space:
$$\mathcal{C}(\Omega):=\{f:\Omega\to\mathbb{C}:f\text{ continuous}\}$$

Consider a bounded family:
$$\mathcal{F}\subseteq\mathcal{C}(\Omega):\quad\|f\|_{f\in\mathcal{F}}<\infty$$

Then Arzela-Ascoli states:
$$\mathcal{F}\text{ precompact}\iff\mathcal{F}\text{ equicontinuous}$$
How to prove this from scratch?

**Attempt**

For a precompact family one finds:
$$\mathcal{F}\subseteq\mathcal{B}_\delta(g_1)\cup\ldots\cup\mathcal{B}_\delta(g_I)$$
So one can always pick one close enough:
$$f\in\mathcal{F}:\quad|f(x)-f(z)|\leq|f(x)-g_f(x)|+|g_f(x)-g_f(z)|+|g_f(z)-f(z)|<\varepsilon\quad(x\in B_\delta(z))$$

Conversely, prove for a sequence:
$$f_n\in\mathcal{F}:\quad\|f_{m'}-f_{n'}\|\to0$$

For a compact domain one finds:
$$\Omega\subseteq B_\delta(a_1)\cup\ldots\cup B_\delta(a_I)$$

Bolzano-Weierstrass gives a subsequence:
$$|f_n(a_i)|_{n\in\mathbb{N}}<\infty:\quad|f_{m'}(a_i)-f_{n'}(a_i)|\to0$$

Take as threshold:
$$m',n'\geq N':=\max_{i=1\ldots I}N'_i$$

So one can again always pick one close enough:
$$x\in\Omega:\quad|f_{m'}(x)-f_{n'}(x)|\leq|f_{m'}(x)-f_{m'}(a_x)|+|f_{m'}(a_x)-f_{n'}(a_x)|+|f_{n'}(a_x)-f_{n'}(x)|<\varepsilon$$

Is this proof correct or do I miss something?

**Discussion**

Moreover, why does the usual proof exploit separability before?

*(For example see wiki: [Arzela-Ascoli: Proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arzel%C3%A0%E2%80%93Ascoli_theorem#Proof))*

Sure for a proposition on its own:
$$\Omega\text{ separable}:\quad|f_n(x)-f(x)|\to0$$
$$\Omega\text{ precompact}:\quad\|f_n-f\|\to0$$

But why both together in a single proof?

Comment: Speaking generally ... Cantor diagonalization allows you to take any sequence of complx functions $\{ f_{n} \}$ defined on a countable set $S$ for which $\{ f_{n}(x)\}$ is a bounded in $n$ for each fixed $x \in S$, and obtain a subsequence $\{ f_{n_{k}}\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ which converges everywhere on $S$. This can be extended to functions on a space $\Omega$ with a countable dense subset by assuming an equicontinuity condition. Equicontinuity naturally arises when dealing with solutions of differential equations through integral operators. And that's where Fredholm theory came from originally.

Comment: @T.A.E.: Yes I had that diagonal argument when I started writing this thread but that seems superfluos if one has a compact domain anyway, or? So it makes sense as a proposition on pointwise convergence on its own but within the proof of Arzela-Ascoli?

Comment: Another example: If you start with a uniformly bounded sequence of non-decreasing real functions on $\mathbb{R}$, then you can get a subsequence which converges at the rationals, and you can show that there is a further subsequence that will converge pointwise everywhere; equicontinuity can be replaced by monotonicity instead. That, in some sense, becomes a compactness type of result for Borel measures on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I think you need the Cantor diagonalization method with a compact domain or not. These are 3-$\epsilon$ methods, and you need convergence on a dense subset.

Comment: @T.A.E.: Yes you'll need the Cantor diagonalization in finite or countable form but for a compact domain you won't need to consider a countable dense set in first place but only finitely many balls, don't you?

Comment: For compact, you can escape it, but not for locally compact. But you can use the same argument for both. Keep in mind that most of the compactness definitions came out of Arzela-Ascoli!!!

Comment: @T.A.E.: True. So then it's good to take just both cases together. Thanks.

Comment: By the way, the definition of a compact operator was an abstraction of the Arzela-Ascoli arguments used to study integral operators, especially their Fredholm properties and index.

Comment: @T.A.E.: Aaaah that's why Arzela-Ascoli remains so important.

Comment: Yes, it's still a good method for proving the compactness of integral types of operators. The machinery after that has been abstracted, but the arguments of Riesz for compact operators basically originated in the study of Fredholm integral equations. Riesz did a beautiful job of capturing the essence of the arguments, and getting at Fredholm index in an abstract way. Interesting how important compact operators turned out to be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider any separable metric space $X$ and a complete metric space $Y$. Then endow $C(X,Y)$ with the compact convergence topology: a sequence $(f_n)$ converges to $f\in C(X,Y)$ if and only if for every compact subset $K$ of $X$, $f_n\mid K$ converges uniformly to $f\mid K$. You can show this is actually metrizable, so that compact and and sequentially compact are equivalent properties, and hence precompact and sequentially precompact are too.

What Arzela-Ascoli says is that a family $\mathscr F$ of $C(X,Y)$ is precompact if and only if it is locally uniformly equicontinuous -- every point $x\in X$ has a neighborhood $V$ where  $\mathscr F\mid V$ is uniformly equicontinuous, and pointwise bounded, i.e. every set ${\rm ev}_x(\mathscr F)$ is bounded in $Y$ for each $x\in X$.

It seems to me that when one puts it in this way, the proof is very natural and easy to remember.

Consider a sequence $(f_n)$ in $\mathscr F$. First, take a dense countable subset $A=\{a_1,\ldots\}$. The general diagonal argument gives a subsequence $g_j=f_{i_j}$ such that $g_j(a_i)$ converges for each $a_i$ as $j\to\infty$. Now pick a compact set $K$, and take $\varepsilon >0$.

Since $\mathscr F$ is locally uniformly equicontinuous, each point $x$ in $K$ has a neighborhood $V_x$ where $\mathscr F \mid V_x$ is  is uniformly equicontinuous. Since $K$ is compact, we can find finitely many $V_1,\cdots ,V_s$ that cover $K$, and where $z,y\in V_x$ implies $d(f(z),f(y))<\varepsilon$ for any $z,y\in V_x$ and $f\in\mathscr F$.

Since $A$ is dense, we can find $a'_i=a_{i_j}\in V_j$ for each $j$. I claim that $(g_j)$ converges uniformly in $K$. Indeed, pick any $z\in K$. If $z$ is in $V_i$ we have that

$$d(g_n(z),g_m(z))\leqslant d(g_n(z),g_n(a_i))+d(g_n(a_i),g_m(a_i))+d(g_m(a_i),g_m(z))<3\varepsilon$$

Since $a_i,z\in V_i$, we have that $d(g_n(z),g_n(a_i))$ and $d(g_m(a_i),g_m(z))$ are both $<\varepsilon$ and since $g_j(a_i)$ converges we can pick $N$ so that $n,m>N$ gives $d(g_n(a_i),g_m(a_i))<\varepsilon$. This means that if $n,m>N$ and $z\in K$, $$d(g_n(z),g_m(z))<3\varepsilon$$

Which means $(g_n)$ converges uniformly in $K$.

Comment: Ah right so the natural topology in this situation would be that of uniform convergence on compact sets. So in that sense a separable space would do the job too. Thanks!

Comment: @Freeze_S Yes, indeed.

Comment: Sorry for invoking an old one, but how do you show the metrizability of $C(X\rightarrow Y)$?

Answer (score 1):

The separability argument does not lose any generality. The reason is that a compact metric space is totally bounded (which you are using), and a totally bounded metric space is separable. So if you assume that the domain is compact then you get that it is separable for free.

Here's a proof of the totally bounded implies separable argument:

Suppose $X$ is a totally bounded metric space, and consider covering $X$ by $N_n$ balls of radius $1/n$ which are centered at $\{ x_{i,n} \}_{i=1}^{N_n}$. Then the set $\{ x_{i,n} : i \in \{ 1,\dots,N_n \},n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ is a countable dense subset of $X$.

I find the separability argument convenient because it constructs the limit: we extract a subsequence which converges pointwise to a function $f$ on the dense subset, and then the limit function is the *unique* continuous extension of $f$ to the whole space. Equicontinuity then guarantees that this extension actually exists and must be the uniform limit of the original sequence.

Comment: Yes sure but that seems like an redundant argument when one has already a compact domain, or?

Comment: @Freeze_S I don't really follow. I understood your question as asking about why you *can* use separability, not really why you *should*. I was trying to explain that if your domain is compact then you can automatically assume it is separable.

Comment: Sure precompact implies separable. But building in the separability argument is superfluous.

Comment: @Freeze_S I'm not talking about separability of the *function* space, I'm talking about separability of the *domain*. You assumed *a priori* that the domain is compact so *a fortiori* it is also separable.

Comment: Ah to bad, I'm sorry I have stolen your time. :/ *(See first line.)*

Comment: @Freeze_S Oh, I made a mistake in saying "precompact" at the top instead of "compact". Sorry about that. (What I said is actually still true, but it's irrelevant to this circumstance).